# Is there any problem with using a number as an id or class for an HTML4, XHTML or HTML5 document?

Tags: html

As the title suggests, I am "afraid" to have elements with either `id="12"` or `class="12"`.
I know the spec allows this, especially for HTML5, but are there any problems you encountered using this?

In this particular case I have `<li>` elements that contain months and I want to give them a class name with the month number (e.g. 1 for January) to reference them in JavaScript. And instead of `class="1"` I do `class="mon-1"`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using HTML4 or XHTML and want your documents to be valid, you cannot use a digit for the id. It will however probably work perfectly fine in most mainstream browsers, since they tend to not break your layout just because of a wrongly named id.

Problems more often occur due to : or . being inside an id name and trying to select those in JavaScript.

I would still advise against using only digits for the id, if you're not using HTML5. Just because it adheres to standards. If you're using mon-1 as the id, that wouldn't be a problem either, it is allowed to contain digits, just not start with one.

If you want to use a class name of: .mon-1 that is perfectly fine anyways, because classes naming-restriction is to not contain a space.

Answer (score 2):

What about using the data-xxxxx attributes on DOM elements? Handy if you use jQuery:
http://api.jquery.com/data/

Basically you have

```
<div id="someElement" data-id="5">
  ...
</div>
```

and you can then read it from your JavaScript code with

```
var theId = $("#someElement").data("id");
```

Here's an example to try it out:
http://jsbin.com/ulujek/2/edit

HTML5 only, though..

Comment: Thanks, Juri. I know about data-xxx, and they are a good idea, but for this particular case I need to use id and class attributes.

Comment: @Fancisc just for curiosity, may I know why this approach does not work in your case?

Comment: Because the markup already exists. Still, my question was more theoretical than practical, I was curious to see if me worried about using `id="10"` or `class="10"` are founded.